# Dúvida MySql - Resultado da consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Galera me ajudem com uma situação por gentileza, preciso pegar todos os registros da tabela "comprador" e seus atributos e caso eu tenha na registros de um cliente na tabela pedido vinculado a algum comprador listado ele me mostre por comprador:

```
comprador.nomeCompr, 
comprador.descCatComprador,
COALESCE(sum(mercadoria.precoMercadoria*pedido.quantMercPedido),'0') as 'valorTotal',
COALESCE(sum(pedido.quantMercPedido),'0') as 'volumeTotal'

from comprador
join fornecedor on fornecedor.codComprFornecedor = comprador.codCompr
left join pedido on pedido.codFornPedido = fornecedor.codForn
left join mercadoria on mercadoria.codMercadoria = pedido.codMercPedido
where comprador.codCompr in (select codCompr from comprador)
and pedido.codAssocPedido = '4102'
group by comprador.codCompr order by valorTotal desc
```

Mas nesse caso ele retorna somente os compradores que tem pedido e não os que estão zerados, eu gostaria que ele retornasse também os compradores que estão com valores zerados, caso eu não utilize a condição where pedido.codAssocPedido = '4102' ele retorna todos os valores inclusive os zerados, mas trás também clientes que eu não quero listar, segue abaixo os prints.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você já está trabalhando com a tabela comprador no SELECT mais externo qual o motivo de `where comprador.codCompr in (select codCompr from comprador)`? Isto não será sempre verdadeiro? Como você não tem nenhuma restrição para clientes por qual motivo diz que trás clientes que você não quer listar?

Comment: Na verdade eu criei essa ambiguidade propositalmente, mas por exemplo estou dizendo na linha '''and pedido.codAssocPedido = '4102'''' que ele deve puxar somente o "cliente" que associado na verdade da tabela de pedidos

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar a seguinte alteração no seu SELECT-->

Ao invés de você utilizar essa cláusula JOIN:

```
`join fornecedor on fornecedor.codComprFornecedor = comprador.codCompr`
```

Utlizar como um LEFT JOIN para retornar os compradores sem um fornecedor vinculado:

```
left join fornecedor on fornecedor.codComprFornecedor = comprador.codCompr
```